# How to print two 2D double arrays?

Tags: java, double

Like from `{{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0}}` and `{{0.1,0.2},{0.3,0.4}}` to `{{1.1,2.2},{3.3,4.4}}`. If the two input arrays are different sizes, method should return `null`.

My code below shows `[[D@6d06d69c`.

What is wrong with my code?

```
public class Homework13_1 {

    public static double[][] sum(double[][]a,double[][]b){
        double[][] newA= new double[a.length][a[0].length];
        int c=0;
        if ((a.length==b.length)){
            for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<a[0].length;j++){
                    newA[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];

                }

            }

            return newA;


        }
        else{
            return null;


        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][]x={{1,2,3},{2,3,4}};
        double[][]y={{2,3,4},{1,1,1}};
        double[][] b = {{1,2,-9,7},{3,4,9.9,1.2}};


        System.out.println(sum(x, y));


    }

}
```

Comment: your `sum()` function is returning a 2d array.  seems like it should be returning an int right?

Comment: flagging to close this as off-topic since it's a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: Excuse me? What is that,do my homework for me"??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays don't override `toString`. But there is [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) which says (in part) *This method is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings*. You could change

```
System.out.println(sum(x, y));
```

to

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sum(x, y)));
```